Whatsapp reminder by using Google Apps Script
I found a code to send messages from Google Apps Script to WhatsApp.
It used also Google Sheets stuff so I deleted lines of code related to Google Sheets.
Could you help me to edit it please?
At a certain point there is 'api_key' field, what should I put here?
Moreover in the fields sender and number I wrote my cellular number because I wanna try to send a message to myself.
When I run the function, I get the error message I wrote "Error, message not delivered.".
function sendReminder() {

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  };
    const requestBody = {
      'api_key': '???',
      'sender': '331XXXXXXX',
      'number': '331XXXXXXX',
      'message': 'Prova messaggio.'
    };

    var bodyMessage = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

    try {
        UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://app.whatsnotify.net/send-message',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            payload: bodyMessage,
            headers: headers,
            contentType: "application/json"
          });
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.log('Error, message not delivered.');
    }
}

The whole code without any edit is this one:
function sendReminder() {

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  };

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl());
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var rangeValues = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 5).getValues();

  for (var i in rangeValues) {
    var employeeName = sheet.getRange(2 + Number(i), 1).getValue()
    var activity = sheet.getRange(2 + Number(i), 2).getValue()
    var phoneNumber = sheet.getRange(2 + Number(i), 4).getValue()
    var place = sheet.getRange(2 + Number(i), 5).getValue()

    var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd MMMM yyyy"); // 21 April 2023
    
    var trainingDate = new Date(sheet.getRange(2 + Number(i), 3).getValue());
    var formattedTrainingDate = Utilities.formatDate(trainingDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd MMMM yyyy"); // 23 April 2023
    
    var reminderDate = new Date(trainingDate - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // Change day reminder
    var formattedReminderDate = Utilities.formatDate(reminderDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd MMMM yyyy"); // 21 April 2023

    const requestBody = {
      'api_key': 'YOUR-API-KEY',
      'sender': '6289XXXXXXXXXX',
      'number': phoneNumber,
      'message':
        '*_This is an auto generated message, please do not reply._*\r\n\r\n' +
        'Dear ' + employeeName + ',\r\n' +
        'Ini adalah pengingat tentang pelatihan Anda pada :\r\n\r\n' +
        'Tanggal : ' + formattedTrainingDate + '\r\n' +
        'Subject : ' + activity + '\r\n' +
        'Lokasi : ' + place + '\r\n\r\n' +
        'Mohon untuk datang tepat waktu dan berpakaian dengan Sopan.'
    };

    var bodyMessage = JSON.stringify(requestBody);
    var result = sheet.getRange(2 + Number(i), 6);
    var remark = sheet.getRange(2 + Number(i), 7);

    try {
      if (compareDates(new Date(todayDate), new Date(formattedReminderDate)) == 0 && (result.isBlank() || result.getValue() === 'FAILED')) {
        UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://app.whatsnotify.net/send-message',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            payload: bodyMessage,
            headers: headers,
            contentType: "application/json"
          });
        result.setValue('SUCCESSFUL').setBackground('#b7e1cd');
        remark.setValue('Sent on ' + new Date());
      }
    } catch (err) {
      result.setValue('FAILED').setBackground('#ea4335');
      remark.setValue(String(err).replace('\n', ''));
    }
  }

}


// Helper Function
function compareDates(date1, date2) {
  if (date1.getTime() === date2.getTime()) {
    return 0; // dates are equal
  } else if (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) {
    return -1; // date1 is before date2
  } else {
    return 1; // date1 is after date2
  }
}

